# How to share the APC user cache between CLI and Web Server instances?

Tags: apc, php

I am using PHP's APC to store a large amount of information (with `apc_fetch()`, etc.).  This information occasionally needs analyzed and dumped elsewhere.

The story goes, I'm getting several hundred hits/sec.  These hits increase various counters (with `apc_inc()`, and friends).  Every hour, I would like to iterate over all the values I've accumulated, and do some other processing with them, and then save them on disk.

I could do this as a random or time-based switch in each request, but it's a potentially long operation (may require 20-30 sec, if not several minutes) and I do not want to hang a request for that long.

I thought a simple PHP cronjob would do the task.  However, I can't even get it to read back cahe information.

```
<?php
  print_r(apc_cache_info());
?>
```

Yeilds a seemingly different APC memory segment, with:

`[num_entries] => 1`

(The single entry seems to be a opcode cache of itself)

While my webserver, powered by nginx/php5-fpm, yields:

`[num_entries] => 3175`

So, they are obviously not sharing the same chunk of memory.  How can I either access the same chunk of memory in the CLI script (preferred), or if that is simply not possible, what would be the absolute safest way to execute a long running sequence on say, a random HTTP request every hour?

For the latter, would using `register_shutdown_function()` and immediately `set_time_limit(0)` and `ignore_user_abort(true)` do the trick to ensure execution completes and doesn't "hang" anyone's browser?

And yes, I am aware of redis, memcache, etc that would not have this problem, but I am stuck to APC for now as neither could demonstrate the same speed as APC.

Comment: APC data is tied to the process in which its stored in. Stop or restart that process and the data is cleared. As far as I am aware its not possible to access information from different processes.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a design issue and a matter of selecting preferred costs vs. payoffs.

You are thrilled by the speed of APC since you do not spend time to persist the data.  You also want to persist the data but now the performance hit is too big.  You have to balance these out somehow.

If persistence is important, take the hit and persist (file, DB, etc.) on every request.  If speed is all you care about, change nothing - this whole question becomes moot.  There are cache systems with persistent storage that can optimize your disk writes by aggregating what gets written to disk and when but you will generally always have a payoff between the two with varying tipping points.  You just have to choose which of those suits your objectives.

There will probably never exist an enduring, wholesome technological solution to the wolf being sated and the lamb being whole.

If you really must do it your way, you could have a cron that CURLs a special request to your application which would trigger persisting your cache to disk.  That way you control the request, its timeout, etc., and don't have to worry about everything users might do to kill their requests.

Potential risks in this case, however, are data integrity (as you will be writing the cache to disk while it is being updated by other requests in the meantime) as well as requests being served while you are persisting the cache paying the performance hit of your server being busy.

Essentially, we introduced a bundle of hay to the wolf/lamb dilemma ;)